# How to allow duplicate email address in Joomla 2.5 not working

Tags: php, joomla

I have a simple problem, that I cant seem to solve.

I have commented out:

```
// check for existing email
$query->clear();
$query->select($this->_db->quoteName('id'));
$query->from($this->_db->quoteName('#__users'));
$query->where($this->_db->quoteName('email') . ' = ' . $this->_db->quote($this->email));
$query->where($this->_db->quoteName('id') . ' != ' . (int) $this->id);
$this->_db->setQuery($query);
$xid = intval($this->_db->loadResult());
//if ($xid && $xid != intval($this->id))
//{
//  $this->setError(JText::_('JLIB_DATABASE_ERROR_EMAIL_INUSE'));
//  return false;
//}
```

but when a user navigates to "http://www.website.com/index.php/component/users/profile?layout=edit"

if 2 users have the same email address it wont let them edit the profile. If you click submit, it just refreshes the page and doesnt update anything.

Is there a way that the "edit profile" page can bypass the duplicate email check?

Comment: Why in the world do you want to do this? Please don't, not only Joomla but many third party extensions rely on the emails being unique.  If you need two account on the site for testing, get another email address!! if you register a user on the site from the backend, the email doesn't even need to be valid.

Comment: @RiccardoZorn we have users that need multiple login levels. IE, owner and Driver. Its possible for an owner to be a driver. But they need to be able to login to different sections of the site depending on if they are acting as an owner or a driver. thus they need 2 logins. many of these users that need 2 logins, only have 1 email address. I would like them to be able to have the same email address.

Comment: Have you considered using ACLs to grant both privileges? I have no idea how your site works, but it's a pretty common requirement i.e. store owner and end-customer for other stores, business owner and mobile geopos user of the app... I never had to resort to such a risky hack, I am hoping you can find a way to make life easier for you (and possibly your customer won't have to login-logout and remember two passwords).